# Check the EC2 machine uptime

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

How could I know the server `(ec2 machine)` uptime? On certain conditions, I would want to shut down the machine if it has not been used for 50 minutes. How could I do this?

Comment: @at0mzk Yes....

Comment: This answer might be helpful: http://serverfault.com/a/809326